# How to query for column datatypes of MSSQL table from python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Pandas read SQL doesn't help me because it infers the datatype based on data queried.

```
df = pd.read_sql("select top 10 * from table_name",cnx)
```

I want the actual column datatype present in the db and not the datatype apt for the data queried. Does anyone know how to get that ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` for things like this:

```
SELECT frs.name,
       frs.system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select top 10 * from table_name',NULL,NULL) frs;
```

This will give you the column's name and data type (i.e. `varchar(50)` or `decimal(12,2)`). If you need additional columns, there are many more that the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Pandas capabilities, but can you run this query?

```
-- Select rows from a Table or View '[tables]' in schema '[sys]'
SELECT  t.name
        ,c.name
        ,st.name
        ,st.* -- Every other information you need
FROM [sys].[tables] t
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] c
    ON  t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN [sys].[types] st
    ON  c.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
GO
```